# cin reads zero after an unsuccessful attempt to read

Tags: c++, vector, cin

I want user to enter values for `vector<double> a_` until no double value would be read. And I want to make a vector of doubles called `b_` which its size depends on `a_`'s size, actually it is exactly the same. Initialization of `b_` have to be near `a_` init. But there is some problem with `b_`, which I don't get. All values of `b_` are set to 0.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<double> a_, b_;
    double tmp;
    while(cin >> tmp) {
        a_.push_back(tmp);
    }
    cout << "A size = " << a_.size() << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < a_.size(); i++) {
        cin >> tmp;
        b_.push_back(tmp);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a_.size(); i ++) { 
        cout << "a[" << i <<"] = " <<a_[i];
        cout << " " <<"b[" << i <<"] = " <<b_[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input is:

```
4
5
6
e
7
8
9
```

Output is:

```
A size = 3
a[0] = 4 b[0] = 0
a[1] = 5 b[1] = 0
a[2] = 6 b[2] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I added some explanations by comment:

```
while(cin >> tmp) {
    a_.push_back(tmp); // read 4, 5, 6 and push_back them
}                      // the loop ends when extraction fails for reading e
```

...

```
for(int i = 0; i < a_.size(); i++) {
    cin >> tmp;        // extraction fails for reading e everytime, 
                       // and tmp will be set to 0.0
    b_.push_back(tmp); // push_back 0.0 everytime
}
```

Note that according to the behaviour of [std::basic_istream::operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt),

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min() is written and failbit flag is set.

After failbit is set, if you want read further, you need to clear the failbit and discard character(s) which causing the error. Such as:

```
// ...
cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
for(int i = 0; i < a_.size(); i++) {
    cin >> tmp;
    b_.push_back(tmp);
}
// ...
```

Then for the input:

```
4
5
6
e
7
8
9
```

You'll get

```
A size = 3
a[0] = 4 b[0] = 7
a[1] = 5 b[1] = 8
a[2] = 6 b[2] = 9
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/IHQ35016)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a formatted extraction fails, `cin.fail()` will return `true`. Any further extraction will also fail, unless you [`.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the `failbit`.

Also, since the erroneous value is still in the input stream, you need to [`.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) it:

```
cout << "A size = " << a_.size() << endl;

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore();

for(int i = 0; i < a_.size(); i++) {
    cin >> tmp;
    b_.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cin use a "fail" flag to mark input failures inside, to return a null pointer so that "while" can notice it. So you need to use **cin.clear()** after first **cin>>tmp** to reset the "fail" flag of cin.

you shouldn't use **cin>>tmp** in "for" loop, as you wish to read numbers once a time.

Here's a working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<double> a_, b_;
    double tmp;
    while(cin >> tmp) {
        a_.push_back(tmp);
    }
    cin.clear();
    cout << "A size = " << a_.size() << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < a_.size(); i++) {
        do {tmp = cin.get();} while (tmp=='\n');
        b_.push_back(tmp);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a_.size(); i ++) { 
        cout << "a[" << i <<"] = " <<a_[i];
        cout << " " <<"b[" << i <<"] = " <<b_[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then for input

```
4
5
6
a
b
c
```

You will get

```
A size = 3
a[0] = 4 b[0] = 97
a[1] = 5 b[1] = 98
a[2] = 6 b[2] = 99
```